# How to create a column that increments in steps of 4 in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sequence, window-functions

I am trying to add a column to my table that increments in steps of four which would look like this:

```
    1
    1
    1
    1
    2
    2
    2
    2
    3
    3
    3
    3
etc.
```

I have been reading about CREATE SEQUENCE, but that does not seem to be what I need.

Does anyone have any suggestions how best to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `row_number()` and integer division:

```
select
    t.*,
    (3 + row_number() over(order by id)) / 4 rn
from mytable t
```

This assumes that you have an ordering column called `id`. I would not actually recommend storing this derived information. You can compute it on the fly, or put in a view.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a regular sequence for the default value, but do the following instead:

```
CREATE TABLE test (col1 int, col2 text);

CREATE SEQUENCE test_col1_seq OWNED BY test.col1;

ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN col1 SET DEFAULT ceil(nextval('test_col1_seq')/4::numeric);

SELECT * FROM test;
 col1 | col2 
------+------
    1 | a
    1 | b
    1 | c
    1 | d
    2 | e
    2 | f
    2 | g
    2 | h
    3 | i
(9 rows)
```

This just divides is by 4, and then rounds the value down.